# Как убрать возможность переходить по файлам после .php?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер

у меня есть страницы (файлы) на сайте вида:
https://site.ru/generator_zagadok.php
https://site.ru/generator_klichek.php
и так далее.

В Вебмастере вижу, что есть переходы по адресу /generator_zagadok.php/zagadki.js при этом страница открывается, но уже без стилей и скриптов, вероятно из-за несоответствия путей до файлов стилей и скриптов.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы либо такие страницы редиректились на основную страницу запроса, либо выдавали 404 ошибку, либо как это правильно сделать, чтобы доступ к такому не был возможен. Спасибо.
Использую обычный хостинг (jino), php 8.0, apache web server

Comment: А что на хостинге говорят?

Comment: а сам файл php из подобного пути, если в конце убрать слеш с файлом, как php открывается или нет? Если судить логике, то у вас файл php воспринимается  не как файл, а как директория, а значит это ошибка переадресации. Вообще бы увидеть дерево каталогов и файлов, да и сам .htaccess